# Summing elements inside tuple of tuples with recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

So my problem is as follows:

I have a tuple with 1 or more tuples inside it and i want sum all the numbers inside the tuple. But something is missing because theres a case when u have a tuple with a tuple with elements inside, it doesnt even checks them.

For example:

```
def soma_els_atomicos(tup):
    if tup == ():
        return 0
    if isinstance(tup[0],int):
        return tup[0] + soma_els_atomicos(tup[1:])
    if isinstance(tup[0],tuple):
        return 0 + soma_els_atomicos(tup[1:])
```

Input:

```
>>>tup = (3, ((((((6, (7, ))), ), ), ), ), 2, 1)
```

Output:

```
>>>soma_els_atomicos(tup)
>>> 6
```

The output should be 19 but I can't seem to notice what's missing.

Comment: ill try it out thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of your code has a logical error:

```py
    if isinstance(tup[0],tuple):
        return 0 + soma_els_atomicos(tup[1:])
```

Supposing `tup[0]` is a tuple, then the recursive sum should equal the sum of the numbers in `tup[0]` plus the sum of the numbers in `tup[1:]`. Your code uses `0` instead of the sum of the numbers in `tup[0]`. You can fix it this way:

```py
    if isinstance(tup[0],tuple):
        return soma_els_atomicos(tup[0]) + soma_els_atomicos(tup[1:])
```

Example:

```py
>>> tup = (3, ((((((6, (7, ))), ), ), ), ), 2, 1)
>>> soma_els_atomicos(tup)
19
```

By the way, I would recommend writing your code with `if`/`elif`/`elif` instead of separate `if` statements, and use an `else` case to handle invalid input types (e.g. by raising `TypeError`).